# How to remove "meta.json" file to be accessible as a route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metadata

I have built a React application and if I try to access the route "/meta.json" it shows the user this:

[image]

This is causing some of my tests to fail, how can I hide/remove it from being accessible?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or something like Next.js?

Comment: @IanH. I'm using create-react-app